# Definitive guide for setting up a Google App Engine app, with domain and sub domain mapping

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, installation, subdomain

I have been used the Google App Engine for multiple hobby projects and I have even published a few of them and setup associated domains with moderate success.  Of the few, one of those apps even uses sub-domain mapping.

In spite of the multiple setup attempts, I have still had a bit of difficulty setting up my domains for new projects and I've had to cross-reference multiple help articles (many found on SO).  Some times those solutions, however, are close to what I've needed because of setup mistakes or variations in my application.

Even with a bit of experience, it still feels like I'm hacking the domain implementation together because there is no good start-to-finish setup for a GAE application that involves creating the necessary Google Apps application, the App engine application, domain registration and DNS setup.

So, could someone please offer a very high-level walk-through of setting up a GAE application from start to finish with the following requirements.

**Requirements**

- A domain should point to the GAE application
- The application should allow for sub-domain integration, pointing to different application handlers.
- Can dynamic sub-domains be easily handled in the application?  If so, what must you do in the setup process to assure that all requests to your domain are forwarded to the GAE app?
- Forward "Naked" domain requests are forwarded to the right place. (There are multiple response to this requirement.  What is the best approach to solving this requirement.)
- If you must create a Google Apps application, when should it be created?  Include this in the instruction list at the appropriate place.

Again, many of the above requirements have been asked on many forums, including this one.  Usually it comes from someone who is in the middle of a problem setting up there domain with their application.  Some of these requirements can be easily fulfilled if certain "gotchas" are avoided in the early stages of setup or application requirements are slightly modified to work around (or with) the limitations of the GAE.

In a nutshell, what I'm looking for is a very simple, straight forward response that provides a list of steps should be followed in order to setup a domain with a GAE application.

Thanks gurus.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask specific questions for things you don't understand, and then write the walkthrough yourself. Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate venue to ask others to do this for you.

Comment: @Drew-- I've been using SO for a few months now and although many questions are rather simple, with straight forward answers, I have found many open questions that have generated quite a few (some times even lengthy) responses to more general problems.  Those questions are then, usually, converted to community wikis.  I certainly wouldn't mind this question receiving such treatment because it seems to be common problem or would, otherwise, be asked  1000 different times 100 different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the steps are independent - setting up a Google Apps account is the same whether you're going to add an App Engine app to it or not - except mapping the domain, which is documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html). Domain registration and DNS setup depends on your registrar, so it's not possible to write a universal guide to those. Handling subdomains in your app, meanwhile, is something that's not App Engine specific - it's just standard WSGI (or Servlets, depending on language).

Comment: Thanks Nick, but this question stems from my last experience.  Specifically, I wrote a rather simple application, published it under my personal Google account and then registered and setup the domain through Google.  Even then, I still kept getting those very generic "Internal Error" messages for a couple weeks and I specifically followed their (Google's) step-by-step instructions.  Even then I solved my problem by mucking around with their registrar's settings modding subdomain settings in the Google Apps manager and eventually everything worked by what felt like "magic".