# How long does it take for a domain to be fully implemented for a new App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, google-apps

A few months ago I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111043/definitive-guide-for-setting-up-a-google-app-engine-app-with-domain-and-sub-dom) because I tried to follow all of the Google instructions, perfectly, for setting up a domain with your Google App Engine application.

I still couldn't get my new domain (purchased through Google) to work properly.  After a bit of triple checking in my Google Apps account and DNS setting tweaks (with the ENOM registrar which Google uses), I gave up and figured I'd just wait a few days to see what happened.

Surprise, after a few days my domain started to work without any problems and I've begun to wonder if the problem was that it takes Google a bit of time to get everything setup on there end.

Today, I've once again published an App Engine application and went through the process of purchasing a domain through Google and setting it up in Google Apps.  After following Googles instructions, going to my new domain points to a generic welcome page ([seen here](https://sites.google.com/a/sc-ans.org/sites/system/app/pages/meta/domainWelcome).)

I have a hunch that I've setup my web site correctly and I should probably just be patient.  However, I've never seen Google documentation stating that the setup may take a while, so I'm still a wee bit skeptical.

How long should I have to wait for my domain, Apps site and App Engine application to be fully setup and functional against my new domain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you register your new Domain name, the new Domain will typically take between 24 to 96 hours to propagate.
Once the Domain is propagated, you can setup your Google App Engine application in few minutes.

Usually you will need to tweak the DNS of your Domain for a couple of operations that does not require more than 10 minutes of work:

1. TXT record creation to allow Google to verify you own that Domain
2. CNAME record creation to map your App engine application to the new registered Domain